# ruby tweet line from text file

Tags: ruby, loops, twitter, readfile, tweets

My code won't tweet from the file every interval, it only prints in the terminal, but not on twitter. I'm also trying to loop it so that once done with the file.length its repeats. Thanks for your help.

```
require 'Twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "..."
  config.consumer_secret = "..."
  config.access_token = "..."
  config.access_token_secret = "..."
end


blog_post = []
tweet_img = []


def post 
File.open("tweets.txt") do rand |line|
    line.each do |item|
        tweets = item.chomp.split("\n")
        #while client.update("#{}")
                puts tweets 
                sleep(30)
            #end 
            #puts blog_post.to_s, "\n\n"
        end
    end
end

puts client.update("#{post}").text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'Twitter'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "xxxx"
  config.consumer_secret = "xxxx"
  config.access_token = "xxxx"
  config.access_token_secret = "xxxx"
end

file = File.open("tweets.txt")
ary = []
i = 0
file.each_line do |line|
  ary[i] = line.chomp
  i += 1
end
file.close

j = 0

i.times do
  client.update("#{ary[j]}")
  j += 1
  sleep 10
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to Twitter:

```
client.update("#{post}").text
```

is outside of your loop, so it is only called once. If you want it for each line, it should be:

```
def post 
  File.open("tweets.txt") do rand |line|
    line.each do |item|
      tweets = item.chomp.split("\n")
      puts tweets
      client.update("#{tweets}").text
      sleep(30)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ok, nvm it does it, had to make some tweeks, but how can I make it so that it keeps looping? @Martin

Comment: and is there a way to get rid of the brackets "[" "]" and the backslash "\" that keep magically appearing in each tweet?

Comment: I don't know the Ruby Twitter API personally. What do you mean by "how to make it keeps looping"? If I understand, you do have a loop on each line of your tweets.txt file?

Comment: meaning once it reaches the file.length to start again....but I guess I can just write a repeat every (secs) function... @Martin I just thought there was a "for" or "while" loop that would keep reading the file regardless when it reads the last line..